# Graphite does not show old stats

Tags: graphite, whisper

We are using Graphite to store stats about our websites. Everything works fine when we want to see the data for the last 24h and 7days. When we are trying to have a look at the last month data Graphite does not show any data.

We collect the data for one metric every 5min and the other ones once an hour.

When I use the GUI this "query" works:

```
width=1188&height=580&target=identifierXYP.value&lineMode=connected&from=-8days
```

And this one does not return any data

```
width=1188&height=580&target=identifierXYP.value&lineMode=connected&from=-9days
```

The only thing that changed was the "from" part.

---

I already ran

```
find ./ -type f -name '*.wsp' -exec whisper-resize.py --nobackup {} 5m:365d \;
```

but it did not help.

---

whisper-info.py value.wsp outputs:

```
maxRetention: 157680000
xFilesFactor: 0.5
aggregationMethod: average
fileSize: 2521504

Archive 0
retention: 691200
secondsPerPoint: 10
points: 69120
size: 829440
offset: 64

Archive 1
retention: 2678400
secondsPerPoint: 60
points: 44640
size: 535680
offset: 829504

Archive 2
retention: 31536000
secondsPerPoint: 600
points: 52560
size: 630720
offset: 1365184

Archive 3
retention: 157680000
secondsPerPoint: 3600
points: 43800
size: 525600
offset: 1995904
```

Comment: Yes, you should change retention of xFilesFactor, but not for first archive, but for the second one. Could you please show output of `whisper-info.py identifierXYP/value.wsp` and your current retentions?

Comment: @deniszh Thanks for the feedback. I updated my questions with the output.

Comment: Your highest precision retention should match your polling frequency. Because you have a 10s:8d retention level, many of your "buckets" are being rolled up into the 60s:31d as "none", causing your original data to be averaged down. Please check this link for info: 
http://obfuscurity.com/2012/04/Unhelpful-Graphite-Tip-9